# How to output SQL arrays in simplified format?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

Working with Standard SQL on BigQuery, I've combined a number of email-columns into a an array of unique emails.

The output though (queried through PowerQuery on Excel), shows as

```
{"v":[{"v":"joe@fakemail.com"},{"v":"joe.bro@someemail.com"}]}
```

First time I see this.

1. This looks like an key-value object with an array as value , and each array value is then again a key-value object. Is this **normal** output? (I'm pasting relevant code snippet below).
2. How do I output [joe@fakemail.com , joe.bro@someemail.com] or ["joe@fakemail.com" , "joe.bro@someemail.com"].

Here's the bit of SQL that led to this output:

```
WITH emails AS (
    select 'Joe' as name, 'joe@hotmail.com,joe@someemail.com' as email1, 'joe@hotmail.com' as email2
    UNION ALL
    select 'Brenda', 'brenda@mail.com', 'Brenda81@TEST.com'
)

select name, 
ARRAY(
    SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(TRIM(LOWER(EMAIL))," ","") from UNNEST(
        ARRAY_CONCAT(
            SPLIT(email1, ","),
            SPLIT(email2, ",")
        )
    ) AS EMAIL WHERE EMAIL like '%@%'
) AS UNIQUE_EMAILS,  
FROM emails
```

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant you're referring to my code snippet?

Comment: yes. i think to answer #2 in your question this will help

Comment: Okay done. Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: Hello, please refer to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#offset_and_ordinal), which describes accessing an ARRAY element. Let me know about the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below less verbose version instead (also with less string to array to string back and forth - so should better perform)

```
select name, 
  (select string_agg(distinct lower(email))
  from unnest(split(concat(email1, ',', email2))) email
  ) unique_emails
from emails
```

if applied to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to convert the array to a string using [`ARRAY_TO_STRING()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_to_string).

```
WITH emails AS (
    select 'Joe' as name, 'joe@hotmail.com,joe@someemail.com' as email1, 'joe@hotmail.com' as email2
    UNION ALL
    select 'Brenda', 'brenda@mail.com', 'Brenda81@TEST.com'
)

select name,
       ARRAY_TO_STRING(
            ARRAY(
                SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(TRIM(LOWER(EMAIL))," ","") from UNNEST(
                    ARRAY_CONCAT(
                        SPLIT(email1, ","),
                        SPLIT(email2, ",")
                        )
                    ) AS EMAIL WHERE EMAIL like '%@%'
                ),
           ','
           ) AS UNIQUE_EMAILS,
FROM emails
```